# Fail to update field in FireStore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a project that connected to FireStore. I tried to update a field in document *userIDKey* inside collection *User*. It runs through the function without raising an error. However, it does not update the field in FireStore. Can anyone show me where I did wrong? Attachments below are my code, an image of my FireStore database, and Demo Updating field.

[Demo Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYFO5.png)

[FireStore "*infected*" field not updating after running through the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTfzh.png)

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
                    if (user) {
                        console.log(user.uid);
                        userID = user.uid;

                        if ((check_bolean != "yes") && (check_bolean != "no")){
                            alert("Please input YES/NO for the following box!");
                        }
                        else{
                            if (check_bolean == "yes"){
                                fStore.collection("User").doc(userID).update({
                                    infected: true
                                })
                                alert("You are infected")
                            }
                            else{
                                fStore.collection("User").doc(userID).update({
                                    infected: false
                                })
                                alert("You are not infected!");
                            }
                            window.location.assign("MainPage.html")
                        }
                    } else {
                        console.log("Cannot get userid")
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add callback listener to the api call so you get sucess or error response.

*alert("You are not infected!")* is called as it's not inside any callback method. So you should change your code like this.

```
fStore.collection("User").doc(userID)
.update({
       infected: false
}).then(function() {
    // update successful here
    alert("You are not infected!");
}).catch(function(error) {
     console.log(error);
})
```

Also, make sure you have set your firestore rules to accept update transaction.